# How can I change language for word suggestion while writing an sms text message

Tags: sms, languages

I will be extremely disappointed if there is no way to change language WHILE writing an SMS without having to go to the phone's settings and changing the language there. Surely somebody in the android team must have been using more than one language?

Didn't know this was specific to phone model. I have a Google Nexus S.

Comment: What phone and messaging app are you using?

Comment: FYI, T9 refers to a specific predictive text input technology. In particular, T9 specifically requires the use of 9-digit number keypad (wonder why it's called T9, not T10 or T8?), and the use of 9 number keys to map to 26 letters and punctuations (for English language).

Comment: Oh heh, I was actually a bit uncertain what exactly T9 was when I wrote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android 2.2's stock keyboard, a long press on space bar then swiping left or right should allow you to switch between languages you selected on `Settings > Language & Keyboard settings > Android keyboard > Input Languages > Select Multiple Languages`.

Note that it depends on your manufacturer, carrier, and ROM whether your phone will have the dictionary for the languages you want to use.

Comment: Excellent! Hadn't figured out you could select multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you "long-press" in the text field, one of the options that pops up, along with Select All, Copy All, etc is **Input method** select that, and it should let you change your keyboard settings.

Most Android keyboards also have a way to quickly change the language on the keyboard itself. On Swype, you long press on the <kbd>Q</kbd> to change language, on the Samsung T9 keypad there's a "gear" button in the bottom-right that lets you change settings.

Do you know which (T9) keyboard you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Downlaod the [Android 2.3.4 user's guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//help/hc/pdfs/mobile/AndroidUsersGuide-2.3.4.pdf).

Read "Change the keyboard language" on page 35.

On the Android operating system, the keyboard language selection is specific for models that use a customised Android version as for example is the case with HTC phones. The Nexus S uses the standard version issued by Google, for which the quoted link applies. I can't find a user's guide for the latest Android version 2.3.6 but the procedure for setting more than one keyboard language and the procedure for language selection when writing texts is the same as with Android 2.3.4.

Does this answer help?